# new items in DataGridViewComboBoxCell not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a Datagridview, partly filled by a datasource, by setting DataPropertyNames.
Partly filled by me in the code.
I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn where cells should be filled when i click the button next to it.
Clicking the button fills the Items of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell, but if i click on the ComboBox, i can't open it to select a value.

(At the end of the function i change a columnvalue to x as a test, this works fine...)

Code:

```
//add the combobox column
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cellcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cellcol.Name = "Cell";
cellcol.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cellcol);

//method that gets called when the button is clicked
private void getAllCells(List<ComponentRow> componentRows, int i)
        {

            //show all cells
            CellFilter cf = new CellFilter();
            cf.customerNr = libraryNr;
            Cell[] cells = Service.Instance.Client.queryCells(cf, new QueryParam());
            foreach (Cell c in cells)
            {
                ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1["Cell", i]).Items.Add(cells[0].cell_name);
            }
            cellsShownForComponents[i] = ShowedCells.ALL;
            ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1["variants", i]).Value = "x";
        }
```

Comment: *if i click on the ComboBox, i can't open it to select a value* -> That means the combobox has no items at all, also you may have to click on the ComboBox twice, the first is to activate it and the second is actually to drop down its list.

Comment: the combobox does contain items (i've checked by debugging). clicking twice does not work either. I do have a click-eventhandler implemented on the datagridview, but as it still behaves normal for the other cells, i don't see why it wouldn't behave normal for the comboboxcolumn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. The problem was that my datagridview was readonly. readonly comboboxcolumns can't be opened.
I fixed it this way:
for the datagridview

```
ReadOnly = false
```

for my comboboxcolumn

```
ReadOnly = false
```

for every other column users shouldn't be able to edit

```
ReadOnly = true
```

Comment: THANKS man! Saved my day as I was playing with and starting to smell about EF6. Cheers mate!